# One Node OpenStack Installation and Configuration

Tags: cloud, openstack

Is it possible to apply the ["OpenStack using 3 machines"](http://docs.openstack.org/diablo/openstack-compute/starter/content/Introduction-d1e390.html) doc,  to "One Node Installation" ?

Any experience/tutorial/blog/howto ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Openstack is capable of running all its services on one machine.  I setup the previous OpenStack release (Cactus) inside Virtualbox by following this article. http://uksysadmin.wordpress.com/2011/02/17/running-openstack-under-virtualbox-a-complete-guide/

From the tutorial you linked, it looks like you can just follow the tutorial and just leave out Server2 since it's just a supplemental compute node.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way to get up and running on one node with OpenStack is to use [DevStack](http://devstack.org). It assumes you're running on Ubuntu, it should work just fine inside of a VM such as VirtualBox.

Comment: ... already done. Unfortunatly fails.  The installation stops on command /usr/bin/git clone -q https://github.com/cloudbuilders/openstackx.git /opt/stack/devstack/src/openstackx failed with error code 128 ( see the log here : https://answers.launchpad.net/keystone/+question/181866 ) with

Answer (score 1):

[DevStack](http://devstack.org) is no doubt the easiest way to get started with Openstack. Its a good idea to read the script, that will help you understand the configurations and more importantly tweak them.

However, if you are looking forward for a safe way to try out an Openstack installation,
you may try [Ubuntu Usb live image](http://cloud.ubuntu.com/2011/10/ubuntu-cloud-live-11-10-is-available/) based on Openstack.  Its good for experimentation and I use it many a times for development to try out API's and command line.

Hope it helps.
Let me know if you need more help

Comment: Thanks Deepak Garg, already done. The limit here, is that I want to make a demonstration to my staff on a server based installation. Do you know a way/procedure to dump the live USB into standard installation, than possibly extend to two, three, n machines ?

Comment: There is no well defined procedure to take your usb installation to a physical machine. [Devstack](http://devstack.org) is the most ideal way for doing a physical or vm installation of Openstack. The script is well documented and there are a few exercises you may use to demonstrate to your staff.
I can help you with that if you need.

Answer (score 1):

Devstack is intended to be used by developers of openstack.  It is useful for demoing a single node Openstack deployment as well as testing changes against the latest git tree.

It is not currently a preferred method for installing and maintaining a production use openstack environment.  Single node or otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

[Mirantis Fuel](http://fuel.mirantis.com/fuel-overview/) and [Rackspace](http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/private/openstack_software/) distros, for instance, have both a 'single node' pattern. You can extend later by adding nodes. They're much easier and more robust to install than devstack. They are also less dependent on your host's linux distro.

Answer (score 1):

Devstack is the best development environment out there. You just need to run one script and it will do all your work for you. You can get more insight by reading the script. But the issue I am having with devstack sometimes it crashes for no reason. And as it's a dev environment, you will have to restart it all over. But still, as you are going for demo purpose only, devstack is highly recommended.